# Django got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_slug'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Создал корзину и пытаюсь добавить туда товар через кнопку "добавить". Когда нажимаю на кнопку, выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError at /add_to_cart/nabor-dlya-domashnego-kinoteatra-sony-str-dh770/
add_to_cart_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_slug'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', base_view, name='base'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_view, name='category_detail'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', product_view, name='product_detail'),
    url(r'^add_to_cart/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$', add_to_cart_view, name='add_to_cart'), # добовляет товар в корзину 
    url(r'^cart/$', cart_view, name='cart'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def product_view(request, product_slug):
    cart = Cart.objects.first()
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'categories': categories,
        'cart' : cart
    }
    return render(request, 'product.html', context)

def add_to_cart_view (request, slug):                                                                       
    #функция добовления товара в корзину 
    product = Product.objects.get(kwargs={'product_slug': self.slug})
    new_item = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(product = product, item_total=product.price)  
    cart = Cart.objects.first()
    if new_item not  in cart.items.all():
        cart.items.add(new_item)
        cart.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

**product.html**

```
<a href='{% url "add_to_cart" product_slug=product.slug %}'><button class="btn btn-danger">Добавить в корзину</button></a>
```

Где я допустил ошибку и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя параметра должно совпадать с именем паттерна:

```
def add_to_cart_view (request, product_slug):
```

Comment: да, я это исправил , спасибо Вам

Comment: @АнастасСмех [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).